# Verizon Walled Garden - internet works

Tags: internet, routing, connection

I keep getting "[Verizon Walled Garden](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/16040)" messages, although I can still connect to the internet. Google.com occasionally triggers the screen and DropBox can't establish secure connection.

I am working at a small organization and I don't really have anything to do with the IT here, however, I'm curious what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the reset button on a Verizon-provided DSL modem-router is pressed, the walled garden mode resets to on. Your IT department would have to log into a hidden page in the modem-router to turn it off again, as explained in the FAQ page you linked to: [How to Turn off the Walled Garden](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/16040).

Perhaps the DSL modem-router's walled garden mode was accidentally on at one point, but it's now off. Some addresses may be cached in your computer's DNS cache or in your web browser's cache as the walled garden page. Try refreshing the page in the browser, or try clearing the browser cache. If you're using a Windows computer, try going to a command prompt and typing `ipconfig /flushdns`.

If it's not cached on your computer, it may be cached elsewhere in your organization's network. For example, if your organization is using a proxy server to cache webpages or a local DNS server to cache addresses, they may have cached some walled garden pages. Ask your IT department about it.

Comment: I'm on mac. How do I run `ipconfig/flushdns`? Is there a Mac equivalent?

Comment: I don't use Mac, but a quick Google search for *Mac OSX DNS cache* suggests you can use `dscacheutil -flushcache` or `lookupd -flushcache`, depending on the OSX version. For example, see [How to Flush DNS](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-flush-dns.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to call their customer service and get them to re-authorize the account. I had a problem like this before and after going back and forth for a few hours, the rep finally removed the "authorization" from the account and I had to setup the connection again.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the walled garden is to help you configure your modem. However, if you are using a verizon version of the modem with another provider, then the walled garden arrangement prevents you from getting to the modem configuration pages.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)